# Ubuntu 16.04 Displaylink driver problems

Tags: drivers

I'm pretty new to ubuntu, I've just installed it on my laptop and am trying to get my hub to work so I can use my monitors. When I attempt to install the displaylink driver I get the following error:

```
ERROR (code 3): Failed to build evdi/1.2.65. Consult /var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.2.65/build/make.log for details..
```

This is the contents of make.log:

```
DKMS make.log for evdi-1.2.65 for kernel 4.10.0-33-generic (x86_64)
Tuesday 19 September  09:57:27 AEST 2017
make KBUILD_VERBOSE=1 SUBDIRS=/var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.2.65/build SRCROOT=/var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.2.65/build CONFIG_MODULE_SIG= -C /lib/modul$
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-33-generic'
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (                \
echo >&2;                                                       \
echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";           \
echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";      \
echo >&2 ;                                                      \
/bin/false)
mkdir -p /var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.2.65/build/.tmp_versions ; rm -f /var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.2.65/build/.tmp_versions/*
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=/var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.2.65/build
gcc -Wp,-MD,/var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.2.65/build/.evdi_drv.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include  -I./arch/x86/$
if [ "-pg" = "-pg" ]; then if [ /var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.2.65/build/evdi_drv.o != "scripts/mod/empty.o" ]; then ./scripts/recordmcount  $
gcc -Wp,-MD,/var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.2.65/build/.evdi_modeset.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include  -I./arch/$
/var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.2.65/build/evdi_modeset.c: In function ‘evdi_modeset_init’:
/var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.2.65/build/evdi_modeset.c:375:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘drm_mode_create_dirty_info_property’ [-$
drm_mode_create_dirty_info_property(dev);
^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:294: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.2.65/build/evdi_modeset.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.2.65/build/evdi_modeset.o] Error 1
Makefile:1524: recipe for target '_module_/var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.2.65/build' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.2.65/build] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-33-generic'
Makefile:21: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I don't know how to run make oldconfig $$ make prepare on the kernal src though.

Edit: The above can be solved by downloading the latest version which isn't the one linked when you go to the downloads/ubuntu url on the displaylink site. What you want is here: http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/file?id=993

However my displaylink is still not working with my second monitor though it has now installed the driver.

Comment: It seems it doesn't support the current kernel yet. And, of course, if you're using an old version, please download and try the latest version from Displaylink.

Comment: I downloaded the latest version from their site which is supposed to work with Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting the updated driver I found I had to edit a conf file here http://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/1181623-displaylink-ubuntu-driver-after-recent-x-upgrades

This however has not solved the problem as to get it working with the monitor now causes my mouse to flicker(though the second screen did work). I'm marking this solved as the issue is a known problem with the xorg driver and should be fixed by them releasing an update nothing more I can do.